# Convert PDF without saving a file

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid saving a physical file when doing pdf copnversions. I am running PhantomJS as a server for pdf conversions, and would like to avoid the logistics of storing physical files.

In the API I see the `render(filename)` method which expects a file name, and writes the result of the conversion to the file system.

I guess what I am looking for is something like `renderBase64(format)` which returns a base 64 encoded buffer instead. Sadly this method does not support pdf - only image formats.

Is there a way to avoid the file save when converting pdfs?

I would like the consumer of the service (other browser) to handle the file saving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're true : the only method to save pdf requires a filename. I don't think there is a plan to change this for the next release.

*To avoid the logistics of storing physical files*, you just need a working directory. Save pdf to temporary file and delete once it has been sent.

A very basic script could be

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');

var Guid = function () {
    function S4() {
        return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
    }

    // then to call it, plus stitch in '4' in the third group
    return (S4() + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-4" + S4().substr(0, 3) + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + S4() + S4()).toLowerCase();
}


var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" +
              "QRSTUVWXYZabcdef" +
              "ghijklmnopqrstuv" +
              "wxyz0123456789+/" +
              "=";

function encode64(input) {
    input = escape(input);
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
    var i = 0;

    do {
        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
            enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
            enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
           keyStr.charAt(enc1) +
           keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
           keyStr.charAt(enc3) +
           keyStr.charAt(enc4);
        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
    } while (i < input.length);

    return output;
}


if (system.args.length != 2) {
    console.log('Usage: printer.js URL');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    var address = system.args[1];
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        } else {

            //create temporary file (current dir)
            var tmpfileName = Guid() + '.pdf';

            //render page 
            page.render(tmpfileName);

            //read tmp file + convert to base64 
            var content = encode64(fs.read(tmpfileName));

            //send (or log)
            console.log(content);

            //delete
            fs.remove(tmpfileName);

            phantom.exit();
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using here a Guid function (to generate random file name) and a Js Base64 Encoder.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that was the case